# /boot directory is out space for new software updates

Tags: updates

My question is what generic file should I delete that won't affect the Ubuntu system. Files inside /boot directory are all ends up with generic. So what are the right files should I delete so that I can install the new updates?

Answer (score 0):

run `sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii` to see all the kernels you have installed.

run `uname -r` to see your currently running kernel.  Do **not** remove this kernel (linux-image)

use `apt-get purge` to remove the other images you don't need anymore, e.g., if you are using 3.13.0-34, remove the others:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-33-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same trouble a while ago and `apt-get purge` didn't work. Although `sudo nautilus` and than „manually” removing „older kernels” (shift-delete) helped.