# What is the easiest way to clean the boot folder in Ubuntu 14.04 when you have 0 bytes left

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel

I have tried to look on ask Ubuntu and all answers say the same thing. I have tried lots of them and still no luck; is Ubuntu 14.04 code specific?  Please help. : )

Comment: You may find another way to solve this, here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/546364/boot-directory-is-out-space-for-new-software-updates

Comment: What did you try, and what errors, if any, did you get?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check which kernel is being used – `uname -r`.
2. Open nautilus `sudo nautilus`, go to the /boot/.
3. Shift-delete "old" kernels (if you "normally delete" them, they will appear in `.Thrash` folder in /boot/ and because of that none free space will be made).